# @WithUserDetails unable to create SecurityContext

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-security, integration-testing

I am trying to test whether certain url are only accessible to authorized users with certain privileges. Because I have my own `UserDetails`, I am annotating my tests with `@WithUserDetails` following the instructions in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html)

My test class looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, ConfigTest.class }, webEnvironment = 
    WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
public class SecurityIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(userDetailsServiceBeanName="myUserDetailsService")
    public void testTemp() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform( get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());          
    }
}
```

The UserDetails Bean from the Config looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigTest extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public ConfigTest() {
       super();
    }    

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

}
```

If I try to run the test I get an exception:

```
TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@1ad535f] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void org.trip.test.SecurityIntegrationTest.testTemp() throws java.lang.Exception] for test instance [org.trip.test.SecurityIntegrationTest@167181f]
j.l.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(userDetailsServiceBeanName=myUserDetailsService, value=user)
```

I suppose this means that there is a problem combining `@Before` and `@WithUserDetails` here. I also tried replacing `@Before` with `@BeforeTransaction`, but this did not help.

I am not sure how to fix this, so would appreciate any help/suggestions/ideas.

PS: Running the same text anonymously (without `@WithUserDetails`) works fine.

Comment: For starters remove your `before` method and simply place `@Autowired` on `MockMvc`. Also the `@Transactional` doesn't really make sense as there isn't anything you can rollback. You are doing a REST call which will run in a different thread. That said the sample applies to the `@WithUserDetails`, it will be available for your test, not for the controller receiving the call. You will need to pass the credentials in the call you are making.

Comment: And please add the full stack trace not just a snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. If I do as you say, how do I tell the test to use my custom UserDetails? (If I leave out the @WithUserDetails part and pass the credentials via `with(user("test").password("test").roles("USER"))`, I get an exception from thymeleaf complaining that it cannot find a getUserName() method which appears in the template (and which is due to my custom user implementation).

Comment: You should start your application you are only partially configuring your application. When using `@SpringBootTest` you should point to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I accidentally deleted it here on SE, when editing the question, but in my code, I do have `@SpringBootTest` point to my `@SpringBootApplication`. Sorry for the confusion. Still wondering how to tell the test to use my custom UserDetails implementation.

Comment: You need to configure Spring Security to use your custom userdetailservice.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I believe I do. At least it works when running the app in a browser.